# Is there a way to create a new php file for every sql entry?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, file

I have a big database sorted with courses, and I have a website where you can look up these courses. Is there a simple way to be able to create a seperate page for each course, which is an SQL result?
There are about ~1000 entries.
Basically I want it to act like when you click on a course, it will take you to a seperate page on the domain with information about that course. 
Seperately making 1000 different PHP files for each course would take too long

Comment: Google search: php sql page navigation

Comment: Do you really want to do this? Edit: As I was typing my original comment, @Obsidian and I seem to agree. They gave more info though. GMTA I guess :-))

Comment: Woah, you definitely don't want to do this! Instead, you want to have a single page like `results.php` and display the *desired* results based on an argument you pass in (through a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable). This way you only need one `.php` file, and can provide dynamic results.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a dynamic page that changes depending on what data you give it. There are many ways to do this.

I'll give you an example of how you can do it with GET requests. So you will be able to view course information by changing the query string in the url.

eg.

```
www.example.com/courses/?id=123
```

Will show the course with ID of 123

The example I am giving you is not complete code you will need to set up the DB connection and query yourself but I think it will give you a fair idea of what you have to do.

```
<?php
// url: www.example.com/courses/?id=123

//check to see if id is passed in url
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $course_id = $_GET['id'];

    //TODO: connect to db

    //TODO: query DB course table to find record with $course_id (123)


    //This is an example record from the DB. you would get this by doing a query as mentioned above
    $result = array(
                    "id"=>"123",
                    "name"=>"My Course",
                    "description"=> "This is a great course!"
                );

    $title = $result['name']; 
    $heading = $result['name']." - ".$result['name'];
    $description =$result['description'];

}

// Deal with if no course is found, ie. no id or id not found 
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !$result || count($result)<1)){
    $title = "Not Found";
    $heading = "Not Found";
    $description = "Course not found.";
}



?>

<html>
    <head
        <?php // Dynamic title using the data from the DB ?>
        <title>Course - <?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Dynamic heading using the data from the DB -->
        <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
        <p>
            <!-- Dynamic description using the data from the DB -->
            <?php echo $description; ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should do some googling on how to create dynamic webpages with php, I am sure you will find plenty of resources and videos that will help.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this! I think this is exactly what I want. I will look into this tomorrow, thank you very much

Comment: It's noble of you to have gone through all that trouble. The question still remains if what they want to do in creating a file for each entry is possible. It is possible but what you submitted doesn't really answer their question. Up until they answer to comments left under their question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, I will have to look into it tomorrow, but I think this should be able to solve it. My problem now is mainly that the results are shown on the home page where the sql query is made. I mainly want it on a different page, where I can show description and links to the courses.

Comment: @reallarz I'd look into using pagination for this. It's a *lot* easier,  believe me. However, the data used could be an issue, but I'm pretty sure that pagination will go quite well and no need to create a file for each entry.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you, I will look into that tomorrow

Comment: You're welcome @reallarz - Oh and for RyDog. Your answer was good btw. I wasn't downgrading it by suggesting the OP that they use pagination.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - yes!

You would need to look into creating a connection to the database using PHP, running an SQL command to pull back the data you want, and then manipulate/display that data on the page using PHP.

If you are comfortable with using PHP, there are many guides out there to help with this kind of stuff. For example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp